# JBoss and Eclipse error : Insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue

Tags: java, jboss, out-of-memory, runtime

While deploying the JBoss or while running my JAVA application on eclipse it says:

## There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.

## Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 1064800 bytes for Chunk::new

## An error report file with more information is saved as:

## D:\dev_codes\iText7\NGA3OMSLayout\hs_err_pid5012.log

In my eclipse.ini the memory allocations are as follows:

```
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256ms
-Xmx3G
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
```

How can I fix this issue? How can I increase the memory?

Comment: Can you place the hs_err_pid5012.log. It has the error that caused. Also try changing -Xmx3G to 4G  it will allocate maximum of 4gb to your jvm

Answer (score 0):

Double click on you jboss server from eclipse server view to open edit view and click open launch configuration. Check VM argument -Xms and -Xmx. If value is not enough for your project increase it accordingly.